# How to extract individual array values from JSON response using Guzzle and Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, guzzle

I'm struggling to get data from JSON response. This is my code for getting the data:

```
$client = new Client;
$r = $client->get("http://my.api.com/get-campaign/" . $id . "?api_token=1235");
$apiResult = json_decode($r->getBody(), true);

dd($apiResult);
```

And I get something like this:

```
    array:4 [
  "campaign" => array:1 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "manufacturer" => "Sony"
      "product" => "PlayStation 4"
      "created_at" => "2015-07-04T00:00:00+00:00"
    ]
  ]
  "media" => array:2 [
    "video" => "https://my.domain.com/421156.mp4"
    "images" => "https://my.domain.com/tv/thumbs/421156-1.jpg"
  ]
  "statistics" => array:3 [
    "runs" => 172
    "firstseen_at" => "2015-07-04T19:06:41+00:00"
    "lastseen_at" => "2015-07-09T12:04:13+00:00"
  ]
  "broadcasts" => array:172 []
]
```

How can I get single values from this response? Let's say I want to display, or assign to another variable the value of `"manufacturer"` and in another variable to store number of runs (`"runs"`)?

For manufacturer I've tried to do something like this:

```
dd($apiResult["campaign"]->manufacturer);
```

But then error is shown - trying to get non-property object!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing object access with array access.

```
$apiResult = json_decode($r->getBody(), true);
dd($apiResult["campaign"][0]["manufacturer"]);
```

or with objects

```
$apiResult = json_decode($r->getBody(), false);
dd($apiResult->campaign[0]->manufacturer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like campaign is an array so you would need to do:

```
$apiResult["campaign"][0]->manufacturer
```

Comment: Still an error - `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Ok. The problem is, like @MrSpider said, I mix object access with an array access.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with object then use following:

```
$apiResult = json_decode($r->getBody());

dd($apiResult->campaign[0]->manufacturer);
```

or want an associative array

```
$apiResult = json_decode($r->getBody(), true);

dd($apiResult["campaign"][0]["manufacturer"]);
```

For more detail read [documentation of json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)