# Extracting json object from array

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am using php/Laravel and i have a response from an API that returns the following format in my controller:

```
[
  {
  "id": "474",
  "room_id": "14",
  "user_id": "20",
  "name": "121001.webm",
  "fname": "",
  "status": "0",
  "date_recorded": "October 17 2018 07:18:51",
  "size": "396135",
  "is_public": "0",
  "allow_download": "0",
  "privatekey": "",
  "duration": "0",
  "record_path": "https:example/url/test.mp4",
  "record_url": "https:example/url/test.mp4"
  }
]
```

I believe this is an array inside of the array is the json object i want the data from, so for example I want the record id.
I have used these solutions with no luck :

```
$response->record_url;
$response[0]->record_url;
```

also tried to encode or decode the `$response`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract individual array values from JSON response using Guzzle and Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008152/how-to-extract-individual-array-values-from-json-response-using-guzzle-and-larav)

Comment: Try using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on your response-object and see if you can get `$jsonDecodedResponse['id']`

Comment: from where you are getting this output in Laravel or in frontend ?

Comment: Also share , how you are returning response from laravel ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JSON string, you have and array with one element being an object.

Now, depending on how you're decoding it, you'll get in PHP and array with `stdClass` object, or array with associative array inside.

```
//this will return array with stdClass object
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data[0]->record_url;


//this will return array with associative array
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data[0]['record_url'];
```

Working code: https://3v4l.org/TJNQ1

Comment: Brilliant ! exactly what i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
var_dump(json_decode($response)->record_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below program and respective output:

```
$json = '[
{
"id": "474",
"room_id": "14",
"user_id": "20",
"name": "121001.webm",
"fname": "",
"status": "0",
"date_recorded": "October 17 2018 07:18:51",
"size": "396135",
"is_public": "0",
"allow_download": "0",
"privatekey": "",
"duration": "0",
"record_path": "https:example/url/test.mp4",
"record_url": "https:example/url/test.mp4"
}
]';

$array1 = json_decode($json, false);
echo $array1[0]->id //This will print the value of id which is 474.

$array2 = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array2[0]['id'] // This will also print th evalue of id which is 474.
```

The second parameter of the function json_decode is boolean when TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Thanks